# I hosted a website using WordPress. I want to create a webpage using only Javascript(to demonstrate my project). How do I Proceed?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html

I hosted a website using WordPress. I want to create a webpage using only Javascript(to demonstrate my project). How do I Proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a page named 'Project' in Wordpress and publish it
2. Copy 'page.php'  into your theme folder and rename it 'page-project.php'
3. Remove get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ) and add your own code.